# How do I run an Automator action, shell script or AppleScript on startup in OS X?

Tags: macos, shell, boot, applescript, automator

I know you can run applications on startup on a Mac, but can you run an Automator action, a Service, a shell script, or an AppleScript on startup instead?

I also know you can save all of these as an application, but I don't want it opening in the dock.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, *login* is distinct from *startup*. This answer assumes you mean *login*, as you apparently refer to the ability to start programs as configured in *System Preferences » Users & Groups*.

---

Run Automator scripts using the command line utility `automator` and AppleScripts using `osascript`. Their `man` pages explain the usage in detail.

You can set a [*login hook*](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2420), but it is rather outdated and deprecated in favor of `launchd`.

You can create [`launchd`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Launchd) jobs by placing XML configuration files in your `~/Library/LaunchAgents` directory. This site contains quite a few rather minimal examples, and you can view `/System/Library/LaunchAgents` for examples of system-provided `launchd` jobs. You need the `RunAtLoad` directive for `launchd`.

---

You still can save your AppleScripts and Automator scripts as applications, and run them as such. To hide them from the Dock, edit their `Contents/Info.plist` file and add an [`LSUIElement`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html) directive as described e.g. [here](https://superuser.com/a/360256/22317). This will hide its Dock icon and menu.

Answer (score 3):

You could save a property list like this as `~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC -//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN
http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd>
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>some.label</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>automator</string>
        <string>/path/to/example.workflow</string>
        <!-- <string>osascript</string>
        <string>/path/to/example.scpt</string> -->
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It has to be loaded first by running `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/some.label.plist` or logging out and back in once.