# OS X Server - disable shutdown prompt or solve it that it won't show

Tags: macos, shutdown, osx-yosemite, xcode, osx-server

I have promt with information that another user is logged in and that this user could loose data when I shutdown computer:

[image]

I am almost certain it's because I install OS X Server and I connected it with Xcode. I have it on my MacBook for work. So how can I fix this? What cause this and have I set something wrong? I just don't want to write my credentials everytime I want shutdown computer but I don't want to loose any data. Thanks for help

Comment: Do you have any other user accounts that are logged in? or perhaps you may have to shut down OS X Server every time you are going to shut down the MBP.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/908869/disable-os-x-servers-shutdown-prompt).